# Sending message to child actor on parent and wait result

Tags: java, akka, actor

I am trying to send message to child actor from parent
but the message doesnot arrive until parent actor completes the onReceive block.
Is the any way to send message to child and wait result on the parent actor.

```
Parent:
onReveive(message) {
    if(message instanceof ChildOrder) {
        onChildOrder(message);
    }
}

onChildOrder(message) {
    Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(childActorRef, order, timeout);
    Object result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration()); /* this always times out */ 
}

Child:
onReveive(message) {
    do stuff
}
```

As mentioned above 
Object result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
line on onChildOrder method always times out and when the onReceive method of parent completes
the message ChildOrder arrives at the child's onReceive method.

It seems child cannot process any message without parent completes first.

Is there any way to send message to child and wait result. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the child to send the result back to the parent, otherwise the parent keeps waiting for an answer forever.

In Child:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    MyResult res = doStuff(message);
    // send result back
    getSender().tell(res, getSelf());
}
```

It is indicated in the documentation of [`Patterns.ask`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.8/akka/pattern/Patterns.html#ask(akka.actor.ActorRef,%20java.lang.Object,%20akka.util.Timeout)):

> [...] this means that the target actor needs to send the result to the sender reference provided.

---

Edit based on the comment:

### Forward message from grandfather to child:

If you need the child to send back to the grand-parent, the parent may forward the message to the child so that to the child the sender is the grand-parent, therefore bypassing the parent on the way back:

In parent:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if(message instance of MessageFromGrandParent) {
        child.forward(message, getContext());
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes. the message comes from grand father actor so i was expecting to cut async. calls at some level and collect results at once. and send them back. thanks again i need to change something now :)

Comment: In this case, you might want to ``forward`` the message. Check my edit.